# RSA encryption in C# of a value and decrypting it in openSSL gives message too long

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

I'm encrypting a string in C# using RSA. The same stub done in python works, but when encrypting it with C# I get issues when decrypting stating "message too large".

```
    public static string RSAEncryptMessage(string msg)
    {
        var publicKeystr =
        "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAp+mrzAmFuuX1o2PZLA3C" +
        "/X3c4BTiHbjhR2mF8N5fha5WuiwxNJHtXbJXka4euzhnEdgp4+9zpc7mplgLAMDa" +
        "+BGKE7bjNrUmrckX2Aaaf+G1O1w1iU40+cTUm0NfZ6K0v4sLCpzqTnvjw5ilvliL" +
        "B5+6vHxvKMHlS6l/tdHgbelv1e7fZZeOVPczS5TDfTkJqMFIoI4KzzcH6Izsxu+H" +
        "EizWrT5zYkOCNLWQIpwcMq3h0EXc/qw7NAg/BRMg6HHVkbMNm3eTVzjDq3o77YKq" +
        "NHo2Plt2U9DeT5WcsEIslL7SjNV8ib0KVHMBaVQFu+5emsI3dn3VWEV5ZPkBngX2" +
        "NQIDAQAB";


        byte[] pubkeybytes = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeystr);
        System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        System.Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters rsaParam = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
        rsaParam.Modulus = pubkeybytes;
        rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParam);
        byte[] bytemsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
        Console.WriteLine(bytemsg.Length);
        byte[] encValue = rsa.Encrypt(bytemsg, false);
        Console.WriteLine(encValue.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encValue);



    }
```

The message I am encrypting is:

```
public static void Main()
{

    Console.WriteLine(RSAEncryptMessage("1234"));
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

The resulting ciphertext is 294 bytes in size. The same ciphertext encrypted using openSSL is only 256 bytes in size. What is C# doing that is causing the length increase? Is this a different type of padding?

Comment: I don't think your `publicKeystr` contains only the modulus, but should also have the public exponent in some encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `publicKeystr` looks to be a complete public key (modulus and exponent), however you're using it to set `rsaParam.Modulus`.

You will need to either extract the modulus and exponent from your public key, and then use these to set the `rsaParam.Modulus` and `rsaParam.Exponent` separately, or change your code to be able to handle a full public key.

If you set your modulus as follows, it should give you what you expect. The modulus and exponent here are simply those values extracted from your original `publicKeystr`.

```
var modulus =
    "p+mrzAmFuuX1o2PZLA3C/X3c4BTiHbjhR2mF8N5fha5WuiwxNJHtXbJXka4euzhn" +
    "Edgp4+9zpc7mplgLAMDa+BGKE7bjNrUmrckX2Aaaf+G1O1w1iU40+cTUm0NfZ6K0" +
    "v4sLCpzqTnvjw5ilvliLB5+6vHxvKMHlS6l/tdHgbelv1e7fZZeOVPczS5TDfTkJ" +
    "qMFIoI4KzzcH6Izsxu+HEizWrT5zYkOCNLWQIpwcMq3h0EXc/qw7NAg/BRMg6HHV" +
    "kbMNm3eTVzjDq3o77YKqNHo2Plt2U9DeT5WcsEIslL7SjNV8ib0KVHMBaVQFu+5e" +
    "msI3dn3VWEV5ZPkBngX2NQ==";
var exponent = "AQAB";

rsaParam.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String(modulus);
rsaParam.Exponent = Convert.FromBase64String(exponent);
```